# Path Message with Velocity?

Tags: ros, nav-msgs, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know I can create a custom message that includes a velocity with each pose, but I'm curious for input from other developers. Is there a reason it would be detrimental to carry a speed command in nav_msgs/Path?

For context, I've got a machine that's non-holnomic and I've created a path plan. The machine is capable of high speed (20 m/s). As a part of that path following I want to determine safe speeds to avoid mishaps. This requires looking at stopping distances, safe cornering speeds, etc.

I was thinking to add geometry_msgs/Twist velocities to nav_msgs/Path, maybe call it PathWithSpeed? PathWithTwist?

Am I alone in thinking this would be a helpful standard message? Or have I totally missed some other method that would serve this purpose?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320162/path-message-with-velocity?/) by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2019-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:
Wouldn't a `Path` with velocities (and/or time, acceleration, etc) be called a *trajectory*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ah, I wasn't looking into the Joint Trajectories as I didn't immediately consider it applicable. I was thinking robot arms, not vehicles.

http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/trajectory_msgs/html/msg/JointTrajectoryPoint.html

That would be it!

---

Originally posted by [rukie](https://answers.ros.org/users/38027/rukie/) with karma: 71 on 2019-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-02**:
Please note: a `JointTrajectoryPoint` encodes the *desired state* at a specific point in time. It does not encode "safe speeds [..], stopping distances, safe cornering speeds, etc."